# java create object from csv data and save to list

Tags: java

I need to read data from csv file, it's vertices values and distance for graph data in a format similar to this:

```
Bejing,Tokio,530  
NewYork,LasVegas,800
```

When I'm reading it from file, I need to convert the input data to an Edge object which has two cities as Vertex object like this: `Edge edge = new Edge(new Vertex(line[0]), new Vertex(line[1]), Integer.parseInt(line[2]));` And I'd like to add each new Vertex object to a list of vertices without duplicate vertices. 
I'd like to do that without hard coding the data into the source code.

Comment: what is your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to read the data "dynamically" since you don't know how to get to the different indexes, right? If so, have a look at [OpenCSV](http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/).

Just import the library and for your example it would be something like this:

```
final CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader("graph_data.csv"));
String [] nextLine;
while ((nextLine = reader.readNext()) != null) {
  final Edge edge = new Edge(new Vertex(nextLine[0]), new Vertex(nextLine[1]),
      Integer.parseInt(nextLine[2])));
  // ...make sure you store this newly created edge somewhere else
  // since the reference is lost once the while loop repeats
}
// ...close/release any I/O resources and continue!
```